# Dynamic resize of input

Tags: jquery, input

I'm trying to have all my input box resize with my table.

My table is currently in a jquery UI resizable div. I've tried the following, but the script gives me a error?

The CurrForm variable contain my "div" with the table and all the inputs.

```
$("input", CurrForm).css("width", $("input", CurrForm).parent(td).innerWidth() + "px");
```

Heres a examble of the HTML :

```
<td>
    <input class="table_Input" type="text" name="ModifyPO_AddItem_Quant" style="width:85%;">
</td>
<td>
    <input class="table_Input" type="text" name="ModifyPO_AddItem_Unit" style="width:85%;">
</td>
```

Thank You

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking? Surely specifying the width as 85% is sufficient? All `input` elements will occupy 85% of the available width, even after resizing?

Comment: 85% look good on when my cell are small (Ex 100px) but when the table is resize and the cell are 500px, instead of having 7.5PX on each side, I have 37.5px.... I would like my Input to always be the cell width less 15px.

Comment: console.log(($('input[type="text"]').parent().width() - 15)+'px');

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code is littered with errors which will prevent it from working. Assuming you need the logic to be as you described in the comments, try this:

```
$('input', CurrForm).css('width', (($(this).parent().innerWidth()) - 15));
```

Please note that `parent()` can only ever have one valid element, so it's quite pointless to pass a selector to the function.